# vb.net System.Drawing

Tags: vb.net, drawing

How can I load picture from file, and show it over graphics which is drawn on the form? For example, I have green rectangle across Windows form, and I want to put picture of a dog over that green area, picture from the file, I don't want to draw it using vb.net code. I tried this with PictureBox control, but picture doesn't show.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean when you say `I don't want to draw it from vb.net code`.  Can you provide more information?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
Dim g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
Dim b As New Bitmap(filePath)
g.DrawImage(b, location)
```

Where `filePath` is the path to the image file and where `location` is the point where you want to draw the image.

Comment: Calling CreateGraphics is not recommended because it can get overwritten the next time the form repaints itself.  Also, the Graphics object that is returned may not be the same as the one in the OnPaint method because of double buffering, etc.  It is best to use the Graphics instance that is passed into the OnPaint override.